# JQuery Click inside other click

Tags: jquery, events, click

All I need is that a click event start a simple modal and click a button that is in this modal, but the second click (triggered by the first click) is not working. :(

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
        $("#botaoTeste").click();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the click isn't working and not that the click event handler isn't properly bound?  When you 'modal' something it basically moves the markup to a new home.  I'm not sure your event handlers will keep, unless you're using jquery's new `on` event binding model, which judging by this example you're not.

Comment: @Pete click without any handler will programmatically click the element

Answer (score 0):

You could separete it on a function and call where you need, for sample:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // create a function
    function clickEventTest(e) {
        // some code
    }

    // set this function on the click of the 'botaoTeste' element
    $("#botaoTeste").click(clickEventTest);

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

        // call the function
        clickEventTest(e);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If I click the button "botaoTeste" it works, I mean, the action happens like expected. I just want that to be clicked when the Modal opens. Maybe I can use the on open from that, I'm trying it now. =]